# set dynamic Layout in onCreateView() fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I use,

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          MyView myView = new MyView(getActivity());
          myView.addViews(getViews());
          return myView;
        }
```

I know that `public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){}`    is called after `onCreateView();`

I will need context in `onCreateView()` to inflate custom layouts. How can I get a valid context (using `getActivity()`) all the time before `onActivityCreated()` ?

**Possible Solution:**

```
View view;
@Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

              view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false); //Contains empty RelativeLayout       
              return view;
            }


    //Now that we have activity, create custom views and add it to the empty container
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState){
      RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
      MyView myView = new MyView(getActivity());
      layout.add(myView); 
    }
```

But this method adds an extra view hierarchy.

Comment: U can create constructor which takes context from your activity

Comment: I would not recommend that. And by the way all Fragments need to have empty constructors. If you want to pass objects to a Fragment you would use a static factory method.

Comment: It does not necessarily add an extra view hierarchy. If the layout which is inflated in the fragments only contains your custom view, then there will be no extra overhead. I will edit my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sequence of lifecycle calls:

- `onAttach()`
- `onCreate()`
- `onCreateView()`
- `onActivityCreated()`
- `...`

Immediately after `onAttach()`, `getActivity()` method returns a valid context. You can safely use it in `onCreateView()` method.

Difference between `onAttach()` and `onActivityCreated()` is as following. After `onAttach()` activity is created but not yet completely initialized. For instance, if there are couple fragments in that activity, they are not yet initialized. After `onActivityCreated()`, activity is completely initialized and all its fragments are created. At this time you can safely perform inter-fragment communication.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes when I hit the back button, getActivity() returns null in onCreate()

Comment: Doing it like this will never be reliable. See my updated answer.

Comment: @dcanh121 Have a look at this official example from Google (search for TitlesFragment). They call getActivity() in onActivityCreated() and this is absolutely reliable. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: @beworker exactly. calling getActivity() from onActivityCreated() is reliable, but not from onCreateView() or onCreate()

Comment: @dcanh121 Look into souce code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.3_r1/core/java/android/app/FragmentManager.java
Line 839: set activity instance,
Line 866: calling onCreateView,
Activity instance is always set at this time.

Comment: In @beworker 's link they call `getActivity()` in `onCreateView()`. Is it really unreliable to use `getActivity()` at that point simply for a `Context`, when they do it in their own doc? I don't buy xaver's answer below that "that's not how you're supposed to do it".

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Context` object associated with the `LayoutInflater`:

```
MyView myView = new MyView( inflater.getContext() );
```